# How to rewrite url that uses get variables with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a .htaccess file that would enable me to write

> sampleurl.com/car.php?car=1&name=Audi-A4

And than it would make the url:

> sampleurl.com/cars/Audi-A4/1

my current code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9][0-9])$ /cars/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9][0-9])$ /cars/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9][0-9])/$ /car.php?car=$1
```

Are there any ideas how could I make this work?

**EDIT:**

Both codes work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /car.php?name=$1&car=$2 [L]
```

and

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cars/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ car.php?car=$2&name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but when I open the website, it shows just the page, without linked css file, how can I link the css file to that webpage?

Current CSS Link code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cars/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ car.php?car=$2&name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Ok it partially, I just have one more question, when I put that code, the php file doesn't link css, so the site is cssless, how can I make it link the css file?

Comment: I was offline for few hours and I think you got the answer from other post. However I don't understand how that one is working for you since you stated in question you want  `/cars/Audi-A4/1` as pretty URL but not `/Audi-A4/1`

Comment: True, I had to add that piece of code to his, but then he helped me so I made his answer correct. But If someone comes across this question I want them to know exactly what is the correct one so at the end this is the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

You can write your .htaccess like this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /car.php?name=$1&car=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Same as anubhava's answer, it works, but it doesn't link css file, how can I make it link the css file?

Comment: @PatrikWWDC can you paste old link of css file's?

Comment: Here it is: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">'

Comment: try this : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/main.css">`